# How to combine two output files generated from kubectl get deployment command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have 2 commands

```
for j in $namespaces
do
count=0
replicas=`kubectl get deployment --output=jsonpath={.items..spec.replicas} -n $j`
labels=`kubectl get deployment --output=jsonpath={.items..spec..template..metadata.labels} -n $j`
```

I want to replace 2 kubectl command with one I am not getting how can I do that?

I have tried searching how to join 2 kubectl commandsin a list

Comment: so basically you want `deployment-name replica-count labels` per row for each deployment in the namespace? is this right ?

Comment: basically there is this code
replicas=`kubectl get deployment --output=jsonpath={.items..spec.replicas} -n $j`
     labels=`kubectl get deployment --output=jsonpath={.items..spec..template..metadata.labels} -n $j`

I want to run both deployment commands in one so let's say  if one deployment is goint on and commands are executing and simultaneously another deployment start then there might be chance of conflict in output of both deployment. So wanted to run single command to store output of both command in one and store that in some list and use from that list

Comment: `kubectl get deployment -n $namespace  -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name} {.status.replicas} {.metadata. Labels}{"\n"}{end}'` will give you labels and replicas in one command. You can sum it or do whatever you would like to process